# CGAL + Find edge length using EdgeIterator

Tags: c++, cgal

I am new to CGAL and am trying to find the length of each each edge in a mesh. I don't see any or length member functions or any way of easily getting the points on either side of the edge.

Here is where I have gotten so far. How do I get either the points on either end of the edge or the size of the edge itself?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <CGAL/Cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Filtered_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
typedef double Real;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<Real> Kernel0;
// Use a filtered kernel so that all predicates are exact.
typedef CGAL::Filtered_kernel<Kernel0> Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;

void Edge_Analysis(Polyhedron mesh){
  float mean = 0, min, max, length;
  int count = 0; bool init = true;
  for (Polyhedron::Edge_const_iterator edgeIter = mesh.edges_begin(); edgeIter != mesh.edges_end(); ++edgeIter){

      Point a = edgeIter.prev()->vertex()->point();
      Point b = edgeIter.vertex()->point();
      length = CGAL::sqrt(CGAL::squared_distance(a, b));
      ++count;
      if (init){
          mean = min = max = length;
          init = false;
      }
      else{
          if (length < min) min = length;
          if (length > max) max = length;
      }
      mean += length;
  }
  mean /= count;
  std::cout << min << " " << max << " " << mean << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  Polyhedron mesh;

  // Read the input mesh from standard input in OFF format.
  if (!(std::cin >> mesh)) {
    std::cerr << "Cannot read input mesh\n";
    return 1;
  }
  Edge_Analysis(mesh);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mistake that should be fixed in order to compile is:

```
  const Point& a = edgeIter->prev()->vertex()->point();
  const Point& b = edgeIter->vertex()->point();
```

You should use `CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel` instead of `Kernel`. You should take a const ref on `mesh` if you want to avoid an unneeded copy.